# Can I replace rolled oats with instant oats in a cookie recipe?

Tags: substitutions, cookies, oats

http://allrecipes.com/recipe/healthy-banana-cookies/

That recipe asks for rolled oats. I don't have them. Can I replace them with [these instant oats](http://www.quakeroats.com/images/default-source/products/1-minute-oats_hero)? How much should be the quantity then?

Comment: You can substitute 1 to 1.  The major difference is in the 'healthy' part of the recipe as quick/instant oats are higher on the [glycemic](http://www.health.harvard.edu/newsweek/Glycemic_index_and_glycemic_load_for_100_foods.htm) index (nearly double). This is likely why there is no wheat in the recipe.  Since Nutrition is off-topic here, this will remain strictly as a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Disregard previous version:  I did not notice this recipe had no wheat flour.)

This recipe gets all of its structure from oats.

Instant oats are pre-hydrolized, so that they cook faster.  Regular oats are just the natural oat, perhaps cut, and rolled flat.  They need more moisture and time to hydrolize.

The recipe will *probably* work, perhaps with a slightly different texture.  They may bake faster due to the fact that the oats are already hydrolyzed.

If you choose recipe where the structure comes from wheat flour, the type of oats will matter less.

Comment: So, if we have to replace how much should be the ratio?

Comment: 1 to 1, use the same amount.

Comment: Means for 1 cup rolled oats, I can use 1 cup instant oats?

Comment: Yes.  The two products are really very similar so just use the same amount.  This is one of those cases where the difference will be very subtle..

Comment: Thanks. Actually I haven't seen or heard about the other types of oats, that;'s why I asked.

Comment: Sometimes rolled oats are steamed: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolled_oats