# Baking great chewy oatmeal cookies with Quaker Instant Oatmeal Fruit packs

Tags: baking, cookies

I recently bought a box of [Quaker Instant Oatmeal Fruit and Cream Variety Pack](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B074PZDS2J), and I want to use a few of the packets for baking cookies.

Can these packets be used in a regular oatmeal cookie recipe to bake chewy oatmeal cookies?

Comment: Are you asking if they can be used in a regular oatmeal cookie recipe, or asking about recipes specifically intended for the packets? (The latter question would be off topic, there may be many tasty personal favorite variations out there.)

Comment: I'm asking if they can be used in a regular oatmeal cookie recipe

Comment: This is related, but not a duplicate (since your packets include flavoring etc): https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/33044/17272

Comment: Is this corporate shilling? Why else would the name be so specific and the link be to the Amazon page?

Answer (score 5):

You probably could, but it'd be a little difficult to get right.

You'd want a recipe that calls for instant oats, since that's what's in your packets. And they're also close to 1/3 sugar by weight, so you'd need to reduce the sugar in the recipe. Depending how much of the sugar that ends up being, that could cause additional problems, because [creaming sugar and fat together](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/3141/what-is-the-purpose-of-creaming-butter-with-sugar-in-cookie-recipes) is an important part of many cookie recipes. If most of the sugar isn't available to cream with the fat, you'll get a different texture than the recipe intended.

So I'd suggest searching for "instant oatmeal cookie recipes" or similar, to try to find recipes that are actually intended to be made with instant oatmeal packets. You'll probably have a harder time finding really good, reliable recipes than you , but I'm sure you can find something that's good enough.

Comment: Good point on the creaming the sugar.  It *might* be possible to sieve the oatmeal, and put the dust in with the butter to cream.

Comment: I wouldn't think that powdered sugar would cream right?

Comment: as the goal is to cut little tiny bubbles into the butter, it's possible that the oat bran dust will do the work.